# What would be the best way to position the image to the right of the hero text (See wireframe.)

Tags: html, css

I've been having a bit of trouble with the placement of the image to the right of my text. One of my friends told me the best way was to use a css grid, could anyone give me any advice on what the best way would be?

Thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sFBR.png)

Comment: post some code...

Answer (score 0):

grid system is the best but if you want you can put image in right by styling float right but in this case you have to 50-50% width of div of text and image.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [`float: right;`](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_class_float.asp) like below. This puts the image to the left of the text, and the text adapts as necessary.

```css
.image {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.softexia.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Acronis_True_Image_2017.png" class="image">
<p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, harum antiopam dissentias vis an. Ex eos soleat appellantur, latine referrentur definitionem vis ex. Est an omnes soluta theophrastus, cum summo imperdiet persecuti ex. Cum ad sint solum recusabo, eu suas quaeque pri, an per
  partem adolescens interesset. Quo eu facer suscipit inciderint, ipsum dictas labitur eam ea. Alia oporteat insolens nec id. Cum quaestio iracundia complectitur ex. Ne mei molestie adipisci salutandi. Alterum maluisset mei te, eu saepe graecis pri, ea
  sed scaevola periculis aliquando. Soleat nonumes adipiscing sea no, altera mentitum ut nam, ut vel verterem convenire maluisset. Ad sea gubergren hendrerit reprehendunt. Ea solet commune pericula mel, nam iusto soleat eirmod no, nec mundi omittam in.
  At pro legimus suscipiantur, eos et quaeque docendi. Vel te feugiat accusam consulatu. Civibus epicurei efficiendi mel ut. Laoreet expetendis nec ut. Eam ad summo vivendo, in elit facete tractatos sit, legere graeci viderer ex per. Habeo petentium reformidans
  vix ne, has posse perfecto at, an his eros invidunt. Ea nam definiebas honestatis ullamcorper, eum ornatus honestatis repudiandae ea. Bonorum atomorum perpetua an mei, sanctus vituperatoribus at qui, eos adhuc aeterno placerat id. Mei cu atqui iudico
  appellantur, duo tollit evertitur necessitatibus an. Eum causae sententiae ne, dico soluta sed id, sed melius constituam deterruisset ei. Duo oporteat facilisi mediocrem ei, oratio integre in vix. Wisi sale saepe te sed, no quis nostrud per. Eu scaevola
  prodesset sed. No his latine accommodare, id vide postea conceptam sea, mei ut recusabo accusamus.</p>
```